Were the Europeans taking Syrian refugees by their national decisions?
Were the Europeans taking Syrian refugees by their national decisions? Or were they encouraged to do so by external actors (e.g., the US administration, or any pressure groups, etc.)?
(Asides from the UN, whom one can expect to be supportive of resettlement to keep refugees out of harm's way)

Which "neocons in the White House in 2015-16" are you referring to?

@F1Krazy, i don't know. just curious.

I think this question needs some context beyond "just curious", because it's not at all clear where this claim is coming from. Is this something that someone else is claiming, or a hypothesis of your own?

@F1Krazy, My own query.

Why would European countries be pressured by what some US envoy to the UN is proposing?

This question seems pretty vague. Doing something by one’s own decision is not in conflict with being pressured or even influenced by someone else. Surely someone talked with someone, so yes/no depends entirely on how you turn the dial for the cutoff of what counts as being influenced or pressured, especially by specific people.

"Hawks" refers to advocates of war. I'm not sure how that relates to lobbying for accepting refugees. Can you clarify?

When I hear "hawk," I think of someone who is in favor of more wars. In USA politics, it is usually the case that the more someone support foreign military conflicts, the more right-wing they are and the less they care about what happens to refugees, particularly refugees of color in some faraway place, so the idea that "hawks" would be putting lots of pressure on other countries to take in humanitarian refugees seems a little strange in an American context.

I can definitely see how someone might think "Well, if someone supports a war, wouldn't they want to take in more refugees to make the war sustainable?" But US military hawks seem to view wars as sustainable regardless of the human cost, so this does not seem to bother them much.

Also you have a vote... click reopen. Btw... Scholz has just made yet another contract, this time 250000 Kenyan will be imported in Germany. Looks they take it really seriously.

@ItalianPhilosopher, feel free to edit.

This question does not show any research. Maybe a more specific question could be asked then. And why does it have to be one or the other when it could also be both? Are there any indication available at all for possible external influences? Why not asking directly for what caused the intake of immigrants?

The question does not seem to be based on the history and origin of the (West) European refugee policies.
In the 1930s and 1940s, the Nazis in Germany first persecuted and then murdered Jews, as well as some other population groups. The attempt of Jews to flee Nazi persecution often failed because no other country would take them (see e.g. the voyage of the St. Louis). After the second world war, various countries made the promise that this would "never again" be allowed to happen. They wrote international treaties and national laws to strengthen the right to asylum.
In the aftermath of WWII and the early years of the Cold War, many people fled areas under Soviet occupation. (Notably, from East Germany to West Germany.) Soon the Communist states fortified their borders and the numbers dwindled to a trickle. Numbers remained low during rest of the Cold War and the laws stayed on the books.
The fall of the Iron Curtain caused significant migration of Eastern Europeans claiming refugee status to Western Europe. This caused some social tensions, but mostly those were overcome with the expansion of the European Union (which has freedom of movement for workers, as well as capital and goods).
The number of migrants from non-European countries was also slowly rising. In the 1950s or 1960s, people in Syria or Afghanistan had neither the knowledge nor the funds to consider a trek to Europe. This changed since the 90s and numbers of asylum requests went up. Europe made some reforms, like the Dublin Regulation, but asylum remained a right for persecuted persons, subject to individual judicial review.
By law, someone who enters the EU and claims to be persecuted for one of the enumerated reasons has the right to an orderly proceeding to evaluate that claim. Yet the claim was now made by millions of Syrians and Afghans, not hundreds of thousands of Czechs and Slovaks.
A somewhat cynical interpretation of EU refugee policies is that they do not want to admit to themselves that the promise of "never again" has been forgotten. Any reasonable, democratic-minded person living under the Taliban will be persecuted for being reasonable and democratic-minded.
A more charitable interpretation of EU refugee policies is that they stand by the principle of asylum, but that asylum should be claimed in the first safe country along the route of a refugee, and that the EU states are not the first safe country. (With the exception of refugees from Ukraine, who got refugee status and support.)
But the law still said that there should be a judicial review of any denied asylum application.
And this is where the Merkel decision "Wir schaffen das" ("we can do it") to bypass the Dublin Regulations comes in. Germany decided that refugee numbers from Syria were destabilizing Turkey, Greece, Bulgaria, and other countries on the route from Syria to Western Europe, and causing a humanitarian disaster e.g. in the Budapest railway station. The promise to take refugees already in Hungary was interpreted as an invitation to come to Hungary, or Greece, or other countries on the Balkan route.
Summary, the EU decision facilitating the 2015 migrant movements was the unwillingness of the EU to change their own humanitarian standards. (And also by something I had not mentioned in the narrative so far, the collapse of Western funding for refugee camps in countries surrounding Syria.)

"but that asylum should be claimed in the first safe country": this is however a new principle that is not present in the refugee convention.  To make it a principle of international law would require negotiating and ratifying a new convention or at least a new protocol to amend the existing one.  This will be problematic not least because it places a disproportionate burden on safe countries that just happen to be adjacent to refugee sources.  They already bear a disproportionate burden, but making such a change to refugee law would make the disparity significantly worse.

The Dublin regulation is an internal EU matter.  It says nothing of non-EU transit countries.  It allows refugees in one EU country to be sent back to other EU countries through which they have traveled (but does not require it).  It doesn't say that EU states aren't the first safe country and it does not and cannot result in refugees being returned to non-EU safe countries.

FWTW, Obama praised Germany's decision to receive a large number of refugees then. As for that being determinative in making the decisions, it's pretty doubtful though, for the reasons explained in o.m.'s answer, to which I'll add that not looking/being hypocritical and coalition pressures was part of it. Germany was then ruled by a 'grand' coalition of CDU and SPD. And the latter also came out in favor:

Sigmar Gabriel, the then-Chairman of the Social Democratic Party and Vice-Chancellor of Germany had used "wir schaffen das" to refer to the coalition government's refugee policy. Gabriel's full sentence was "peace, humanity, solidary, justice: these are among our European values. Now we have to prove it. I'm sure we can do it".

Yeah, Obama also increased the number of refugees accepted in the US, but by a much smaller number. So, was he relieved/happy that Germany stepped up? Probably. How much pressure/encouragement did he exercice beforehand will probably not be known for some time, until US archives on this are declassified etc.
FWTW, Obama also praised the later (next year) deal between EU and Turkey that essentially obliged the latter to keep Syrians there, in exchange for money.

In comments to German daily Bild published Saturday, Obama praised Merkel's "political and moral leadership" in acting on an obligation to help people fleeing horrific conditions.
He said that the EU-Turkey agreement "is a step toward a more equitable way of sharing this responsibility." Obama added: "As the agreement is implemented, it will be essential that migrants are treated properly and that human rights are upheld."

And he did explain at least that he didn't see smaller countries taking the majority of these as feasible:

“As I've said before, a small number of countries, like Greece, can't be expected to bear such a heavy burden alone," Obama told the [Greek] newspaper.

Yeah, he did seem to spin the Turkey-EU deal into a flow-management one:

“That's why we continue to support the deal between the EU and Turkey as the best hope for managing arrivals in Europe in a way that's orderly and humane," Obama said, referring to a deal between Ankara and Brussels to halt a refugee influx to European territory by using Turkish soil.


And if you want to talk about hawks here (in the usual sense of supporting some military intervention be it for humanitarian reasons), Merkel appeared to bit more of that on this issue, but was turned down by Obama

But the US president ruled out establishing “safe zones” inside Syria, while the German chancellor stood by the idea as part of the ceasefire plan.
Obama said: “As a practical matter, sadly, it is very difficult to see how it would operate short of us being willing to militarily take over a chunk of that country. And that requires a big military commitment to protect refugees from attacks.”


Before it was change to something about the Illuminati, the Q was specifically asking if some US 'hawks' lobby did this.
